# ui-router not loading template

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am trying to implement a simple ui-router, I am probably missing something simple, but I cannot see where my mistake is, I have this in my app.js

```
 angular.module('tourOfHonorApp', ['ui.router'])
    .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
     $stateProvider
     .state('app', {
        url:'/',
           views: {
                'header': {
                    template : '<h1>Header</h1>'
                },
                'content': {
                     template : '<h1>To be Completed</h1>'
                },
                    'footer': {
                       template : '<h1>Footer</h1>'
               }
           }
       });
    });
```

Inside my index.html I have the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Tour Of Honor</title>
</head>
<body ng-app="tourOfHonorApp">
    <div ui-view="header"></div>
    <div ui-view="content"></div>
    <div ui-view="footer"></div>

    <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

So can anyone tell me what I am missing? Why won't this code load in my template?
EDIT:
Here is the server.js code I have to setup the nodejs server:

```
var connect = require('connect');
var serveStatic = require('serve-static');
connect().use(serveStatic(__dirname)).listen(8080, function(){
    console.log('Server running on 8080...');
});
```

Thanks for any help you can give me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the home state as the default state by adding 
`$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');` above `$stateProvider`.

Comment: This fixed it. Thanks. I thought that was optional. I was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure you are serving your files from server. And also you have configure your server to redirect all the URL requests to index.html. Please refer the following link: 
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode